# Bootstrap only mobile view (three lines)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand enough from Bootstrap.
How do I use Bootstrap to only show the mobile view (the three lines) at every resolution on my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show the 3 lines at every resolution of your website.  Bootrap only condenses the `nav` as the screen gets smaller.  If you want to show the 3 lines you'll have to find the CSS for that in the bootstrap file and mimic it with new CSS conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system and change the value of `@grid-float-breakpoint` to `@screen-lg` or to a very large pixel value (ex. `9000px`). Then download the updated bootstrap file with the "Compile and Download" button at the bottom of the page. Use the new files in your site files and the navbar will stay collapsed up until the browser is the width that you set.